# Example of pysmb

Tags: python, windows, samba

Could you give me an example of using pysmb library to connect to some samba server?
I've read there's
class smb.SMBConnection.SMBConnection(username, password, my_name, remote_name, domain='', use_ntlm_v2=True)
but i can't figure out how to use it

Answer (score 20):

I have been using pysmb for network shares enumeration lately, and found that it is not so easy to find good / complete examples. I'd refer you to a small script that I wrote for enumerating smb shares with pysmb: https://github.com/n3if/scripts/tree/master/smb_enumerator

For the sake of completeness, also, I post here the code snippet that accomplishes the connection and enumeration:

```
from smb import SMBConnection

try:
    conn = SMBConnection(username,password,'name',system_name,domain,use_ntlm_v2=True,
                         sign_options=SMBConnection.SIGN_WHEN_SUPPORTED,
                         is_direct_tcp=True) 
    connected = conn.connect(system_name,445)

    try:
        Response = conn.listShares(timeout=30)  # obtain a list of shares
        print('Shares on: ' + system_name)

        for i in range(len(Response)):  # iterate through the list of shares
            print("  Share[",i,"] =", Response[i].name)

            try:
                # list the files on each share
                Response2 = conn.listPath(Response[i].name,'/',timeout=30)
                print('    Files on: ' + system_name + '/' + "  Share[",i,"] =",
                                       Response[i].name)
                for i in range(len(Response2)):
                    print("    File[",i,"] =", Response2[i].filename)
            except:
                print('### can not access the resource')
    except:
        print('### can not list shares')    
except:
    print('### can not access the system')
```

Comment: What if samba server has a 'GUEST' login. what to provide for username and password field in that case?

Comment: I'd say User=GUEST and Password='' but I should try it.

Answer (score 8):

The SMBConnection class will allow you to access the files on the remote Samba server in blocking mode.

To retrieve the list of the files in a shared folder on the remote server,

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
conn = SMBConnection(userid, password, client_machine_name, remote_machine_name, use_ntlm_v2 = True)
conn.connect(server_ip, 139)
filelist = conn.listPath('shared_folder_name', '/')
```

The returned filelist will be a list of `SharedFile` instances.

More examples can be found in the `tests/SMBConnectionTests` folder in the pysmb source package.

Comment: Thanks. What are the client_machine_name, and remote_machine_name variables even supposed to look like?  Which part of the address do I use? do I include "smb://" in the remote name?

Answer (score 4):

I had a challenging time figuring out how to use [`pysmb`](https://pypi.org/project/pysmb/) module, but managed to get it working.

I'm using Python 3.10.15 on Windows 10 64-bit, using `pysmb` to connect to a network share within an enterprise domain.  For my example, assume the following network share path using full `UNC` notation:

`\\SHARENAME\RootDirectory\Subdirectory`

Somethings to consider when using the [`SMBConnection Class`](https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html):

1. `my_name` string can be anything, even blank `""`.  I used `socket.gethostname()`
2. `remote_name` string must be the hostname of the network share (ie: `SHARENAME` from above example)
3. `ip` string can be the network share's IP address (such as using `socket.gethostbyname("SHARENAME")` or the same name used for `remote_name`
4. `service_name` string is a root directory under `remote_name` (ie: `RootDirectory` from above example)
5. `path` string is the subdirectories under `service_name` (ie: `Subdirectory` from above example.

   - `path` string can contain `\\` or `/` to signify a subdirectory.  You can even use it mixed (ex: `\\Subdirectory/SubSubdirectory`)

See [SharedFile Class](https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SharedFile.html) for a list of attributes that is available when using [`listPath()`](https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html#smb.SMBConnection.SMBConnection.listPath)

```py
from smb.base import SharedFile
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

listSharedFileObj = []

# Using context manager to automatically close connection with code block finishes
with SMBConnection("username", "password", "my_name", "remote_name", "MYDOMAIN") as smbconn:
    # "You must call this method before attempting any of the file operations with the remote server."
    # https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html#smb.SMBConnection.SMBConnection.connect
    smbconn.connect("IP address or remote_name")

    # Returns: A list of "smb.base.SharedFile" instances
    # https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html#smb.SMBConnection.SMBConnection.listPath
    listSharedFileObj = smbconn.listPath("ROOTDIRECTORY", "/Subdirectory/SubSubdirectory")

# Pre annotate for type-hinting SharedFile object
item: SharedFile

for item in listSharedFileObj:
    print(item.filename)
```

Answer (score 3):

For example you want to store a file via pysmb same as this:

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

file_obj = open('image.png', 'rb')

connection = SMBConnection(username=username,
                           password=password,
                           remote_name=remote_name,  # It's net bios  name
                           domain=domain,
                           use_ntlm_v2=True)

connection.connect(ip=host)  # The IP of file server

connection.storeFile(service_name=service_name,  # It's the name of shared folder
                     path=path,
                     file_obj=file_obj)
connection.close()
```