# How to transfer files to multiple remote servers using python?

Tags: python

I want to transfer files using python from server1 and need to transfer this file to multiple servers (server2,server3,server4) and each have different username & password.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250283/how-to-scp-in-python

Answer (score 0):

`pysmb` is a pretty nice library for this.  It's also OS independent, although it would require some form of hard-coded passwords.

https://pythonhosted.org/pysmb/

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248796/example-of-pysmb) for an example of pysmb usage.